# loadStrings() in Javascript error

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have been trying to make a simple web app using the promising p5.js library, but I am stuck and don't know how to move forward. It's really a mystery to me why the following lines don't work. I am just trying to load a simple text file and I can't. It keeps saying that it's empty when obviously it is not. I am not doing anything different from the [default example](https://github.com/lmccart/p5.js/blob/master/examples/async/loadStrings_callback/sketch.js) show on p5js' website.

In fact I also tried the default example, replacing the string to load with:
http://quarx.asfa.gr/data.txt
and nothing. My server shows that it is sending the string... I don't know what p5js is doing. Any idea? Code follows below.

```
var result;
var processedResult;

function setup() {
   createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
   var URL = "http://quarx.asfa.gr/data.txt";
   result = loadStrings(URL, getHistoryState);
}

function draw() {
   background(0);
   ellipse(50, 50, 80, 80);
   textSize(50);
   text(processedResult, 300,300);
}

function getHistoryState() {
   processedResult = result;
}
```

Comment: I assume `getHistoryState` is a callback. It is setting `processedResult` to `result` before `result` has gotten any value. Without knowing anything about p5.js, I assume the callback is called with a parameter of the data in question. That is what you need to set `processedResult` or `result` to.

Answer (score 1):

you have to load your data from the same domain your script/page is hosted at.

have a look into [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). especially [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules):
[image]

Comment: you are right. I tried it again with a file on the same domain and it worked. But, what I don't understand is if I want to use data from another site (using let's say its API) how would I do it? Would I not use one of these functions?
After all this example https://github.com/lmccart/p5.js/blob/master/examples/async/loadJSON_callback/sketch.js on p5.js' documentation loads the temperature of a city from another page/different domain and displays the values on the page. How come they are allowed to do that?
I noticed that they do it using JSON. Is that the trick?

Comment: loadJson probably is able to use jsonp. with jsonp you can do cross origin requests. although this does not work for plain text. a lot of apis have jsonp support.

Answer (score 0):

The function that draws the text, `draw()`, gets called by the API immediately after `setup()`, so most probably before the callback (`getHistoryState()`) has had the chance to set any value to `processedResult`.

Either add `draw()` at the end of `getHistoryState()` as such:

```
function getHistoryState() {
   processedResult = result;
   draw();
}
```

or simply get rid of `getHistoryState()`, to end up with:

```
var result;

function setup() {
   createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
   var URL = "http://quarx.asfa.gr/data.txt";
   result = loadStrings(URL, draw);
}

function draw() {
   background(0);
   ellipse(50, 50, 80, 80);
   textSize(50);
   text(result, 300,300);
}
```

But in both cases, `draw()` we be called twice (after `setup()` and then through the callback). If that's not what you want, rename `draw()` to something else (or add a statement at the beginning of `draw()` to return if `processedResult`/`result` is still empty).

Comment: I tried using this example https://github.com/lmccart/p5.js/blob/master/examples/async/loadJSON_preload/sketch.js exactly as it is, just replacing it with my service's URL (http://terataki.x64.me/history/) but it returns an error in the loadJSON line saying:
"SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"
Any ideas what that might be about?